# PLS-DA deal with Missing values

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, na

I am performing an **OPLSDA**, **all my columns have some missing values**.

I am following these instructions: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ropls/inst/doc/ropls-vignette.html

This is my code:

```
    if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.10")
BiocManager::install("ropls")
library(ropls)

dataMatrix=df.Baseline.All[,c(6:63,74:143)]
dataMatrix= dataMatrix[c(23:294),]

dataMatrix = as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(dataMatrix, as.numeric)))

str(dataMatrix)
class(dataMatrix)


sampleMetadata = df.Baseline.All[,c(2,165,168,192)]
sampleMetadata= as.data.frame(sampleMetadata)

attach(df.Baseline.All)
dev.off()
view(dataMatrix)

dev.off()
view(sampleMetadata)


adds.pca <- opls(dataMatrix)
```

adds.pcs <- opls(dataMatrix) gives me an error

```
Error: 'x' contains columns with 'NA' only
```

**how can I handle Missing data??**

**This is how SIMCA software deals with missing values:** 
"Put simply the NIPALS algorithm interpolates the missing point using a least squares fit but give the
missing data no influence on the model. Successive iterations refine the missing value by simply
multiplying the score and the loading for that point. Many different methods exist for missing data,
such as estimation but they generally converge to the same solution. Missing data is acceptable if they
are randomly distributed. Systematic blocks of missing data are problematic. "

**How would you do this in R?**

Thanks!
lili

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have whole columns with NAs only.  You should remove those columns from your data before attenpting to perform PCA.  I incidentally created a function to detect which columns are all NAs.

```
NAcols <- function(X){
  thecols <- apply(X, 2, function(x){sum(is.na(x))}) == dim(X)[1]
  return(thecols)
}

dataMatrixClean <- dataMatrix[,NAcols(dataMatrix)]

adds.pca <- opls(dataMatrixClean)
```

Answer (score 0):

pcaMethods in Bioconductor has a proper implementation of NIPALS PCA which handles missing data inherently - no need to remove rows or columns with missing data. NIPALS is an algorithm that does alternating calculations to calculate the scores and loadings by simply skipping the missing data and only using data that is present.
Unfortunately and somewhat surprisingly there does not seem to be a PLS function written in R that performs NIPALS-PLS correctly allowing for missing data. The only option I know is the commercial SIMCA or Unscrambler software. The algorithm is published in the literature so possible to build your own.